# removing illegal characters from url / filename / foldername?

Tags: file-upload, rename

Is there a open source or free tool that can go through a directory and remove illegal characters from file? so I then then upload them to SharePoint.

Also, is there a tool like explorer that can do the transfer faster than Document Library explorer. Because it's super slow. I even tried it from the SQL box. for example, I open the document libray in IE and then did a windows explorer view to drag and drop thinking it doesnot have to do lots of traveling over the network and hoping for faster load. but it was same as when i was doing it from my desktop.

Would it be faster if I am on the WFE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your IE options and disable if it's enabled, the Automatically detect settings option from the LAN Settings in the Connections tab. That will speed up transfer rates.

As for your other question, I treat that with education instead of with code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, We received thousands of files from an acquistion so we dont have any control over what they did as far as file naming. And thanks for the IE option to make things faster. Thank you Eric.

Comment: File loads really really faster. 40 files about 43 MB used to say 2+ hours. With your suggestion it took about 2/3 minutes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/ This is a good tool and it let you input a variety of illegal characters (except *, ? and +,\ because they interfere with python regex).